# Tibetan Mantras with Latex

Tags: fonts, languages, letters

I'm a LaTeX beginner and just trying to find out, if it is possible to use LaTeX to display Tibetan Mantras and discovered the package `ctib`, which seems to be quite powerful. But I cannot find out, if it is possible to put the sign `\tibSnaldan`, which is contained in the package, ON TOP of the letters - as you see it if you "google" a picture of the Tibetan letter HUNG. 
I've already conducted hours of research on the Internet but could't find a solution. (`\stackrel` doesn't work as the Tibetan letters disappear...)

I would be so thankful if someone could help me!!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to typeset the letters?

Comment: It's still a work in progress, and probably a bit unrelated, but your question inspired me to [create this (done in Tikz)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hWI7n.png). I basically recreated the image [in the Wikipedia article](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%E1%B9%83_Ma%E1%B9%87i_Padme_H%C5%AB%E1%B9%83). It's supposed to be a flower of lotus.

Answer (score 5):

Try unicode, with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\tibetan{TibMachUni.ttf}
\def\yig{{\protect\tibetan ༃  \char"0F03}}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{5}{\yig}
\bgroup
\LARGE\tibetan
\noindent༆ །ཨ་ཡིག་དཀར་མཛེས་ལས་འཁྲུངས་ཤེས་བློ  འི་\par
གཏེར༑ །ཕས་རྒོལ་ཝ་སྐྱེས་ཟིལ་གནོན་གདོང་ལྔ་བཞིན།།\par
ཆགས་ཐོགས་ཀུན་བྲལ་མཚུངས་མེད་འཇམ་དབྱངསམཐུས།།\par
མཧཱ་མཁས་པའི་གཙོ་བོ་ཉིད་འགྱུར་ཅིག། །མངྒལཾ༎\par
བསྒྲོགས
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the ctib package states, it was a temporary solution until unicode support matured.

Answer (score 2):

In to the [TeX source of ctib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/tibetan/ctib/texinput/ctib.tex), there's the command `\V{}{}` predefined for stacking two letters, but not more than two. But there's also a predefined command for HUNG: `\hung`. 
I changed the definition to have `\tibSnaldan` instead on top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctib}

\begin{document}
{\tib \V{h}{'u}}  % stack 2 letters
{\tib \hung}    % predefined command for HUNG
{\tib \ooalign{{\raise0.7\fontdimen5\font\hbox{\hskip0.15em \tibSnaldan}}
        \cr\V{h}{'u}} % changed definition of \hung for use with \tibSnaldan

\end{document}
```

[image: {\tib \V{h}{'u}} {\tib \hung} and \hung with \tibSnaldan]

`\stackrel` is only usable in math environment.